# Created a split function, but it's not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x

As a practice question, I created a split function, which basically does the same thing as `str.split()`. However, for my first test value it seems that the last word is being ignored and not being added to the list. I understand that it is because there is no 'end' character being compared, so it is skipping my if statement, and not adding the word.

I was wondering if someone could take a look and help improve the code, so that the word is added maybe outside of the if statement, so that it won't ignore the end word.

```
def split(string):
    words = []
    char_to_split = [' ', '\n', '\t']
    word = ""
    for ch in string:
        if ch in char_to_split:
            if word != "":
                words.append(word)
                word = ""
        else:
            word += ch
    if len(words) != 0:
        return words
    else:
        return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(split('duff_beer 4.00'))
    print(split('a b c\n'))
    print(split('\tx   y \n  z '))
    print(split(''))
```

I thought about adding a statement:

```
if word not in words:
       words.append(word)
```

Before I return the list. However, the issue with that is if I had a string that repeated the same word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that if there isn't a character that splits at the end of the string, what you already have inside word isn't added to words.

Append the word at the end if word isn't empty.

Edit: kindall pointed out that it wouldn't work on strings with just one word so I moved the condition outside the `if len(words) != 0`

```
def split(string):
    words = []
    char_to_split = [' ', '\n', '\t']
    word = ""
    for ch in string:
        if ch in char_to_split:
            if word != "":
                words.append(word)
                word = ""
        else:
            word += ch
    if word: words.append(word) # add this
    if len(words) != 0:
        return words
    else:
        return None

print(split('duff_beer 4.00'))
>>> ['duff_beer', '4.00']
```

Edit thanks to @k

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: That won't work if there's only one word, becasue `len(words)` is 0 at that point.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. That particular scenario did not cross my mind.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to just do `split` without any parameters, because default it's `None` so that already can split on `' '`, `'\n'` and `'\t'`:

```
s='hello blah\t\nBlahFooBar'
print(s.split())
```

Output:

```
['hello', 'blah', 'BlahFooBar']
```

This does even more, splits on i.e (`'   '`,`'\n    ') etc...